# Agda stdlib Vec calling last after doing fromList on a List

Tags: list, vector, agda

I have the following function:

```
natListLast : List ℕ → ℕ
natListLast nats = v.last (v.fromList nats)
```

and I currently get this error:

```
l.foldr (λ _ → suc) 0 nats != suc _n_126 of type ℕ
when checking that the expression fromList nats has type
Vec ℕ (1 + _n_126)
```

I would like to know how I can call `last` on `v.fromList nats` when `v.fromList` returns `Vec A (length xs)`. How can I tell the compiler that `length xs` is equal to `1 + _n_126`?

Thanks!

I also tried doing:

```
natListLast : List ℕ → ℕ
natListLast nats = v.last {l.length nats} (v.fromList nats)
```

since `last` has this signature:

```
last : ∀ {n} → Vec A (1 + n) → A
```

I thought that I could pass the length of nats in as the implicit argument for `last` but I get this error:

```
ℕ !=< Level
when checking that the inferred type of an application
  ℕ
matches the expected type
  Level
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I tell the compiler that length xs is equal to 1 + _n_126?

Think about this question for a second. How can *you* tell that `length xs` is equal to `1 + _n_126`? What if `xs = []` and thus `length xs = 0`? The answer is you can't, so don't expect Agda to do so either!

To fix the problem, you'll need to pattern match on `xs` to make sure it is non-empty:

```
natListLast : List ℕ → ℕ
natListLast nats@(x ∷ xs) = v.last (v.fromList nats)
natListLast []            = {!!}
```

I'll leave it up to you what to return in the second case.

---

For the second problem, you'll need to check the full type of `last` (using `C-c C-d` in Emacs):

```
{A.a : Agda.Primitive.Level} {A : Set A.a} {n : ℕ} →
v.Vec A (suc n) → A
```

As you can see, there are two hidden arguments that come before the length `n` (these have been inserted by [automatic variable generalization](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1.1/language/generalization-of-declared-variables.html)). To pass the argument `n` directly without passing those previous two arguments, you can name the argument, for example `last {n = l.length nats}`.